# Un-usual behavior on AJAX post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

When I try to post a symbol `??` two times through AJAX jQuery it posts like this `jQuery18306004520743153989_1413985407818`. For example if I post this: `What ??` then it posts like `What jQuery18306004520743153989_1413985407818` and if I post like: `What ???` then it posts like this: `What jQuery18306004520743153989_1413985407818?` <-- Notice the ending one `?`

Why it is so?

My jQuery posting code is:

```
$( ".textbox2" ).on( 'keypress', function (e) {

            if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey)
            {
                e.preventDefault();

                var message = $( "#message" ).val(),
                    privateid = $( "#private" );

                if (message == '')
                {
                    alert( "Message is missing!!" );
                    return;
                }

                if (privateid.is( ':checked' ) ? 1 : 0)
                {
                    var privateidVal = privateid.val();
                }

                $.ajax( {
                            type     : "post",
dataType: "json",
                            url      : "chat_insert.php",
                            data     : "message=" + message + "&private=" + privateidVal + "&action=addcomment",
                            success  : function (data) {

                                showComment();
                                document.getElementById( 'message' ).value = '';
                                document.getElementById( 'message' ).focus();
                                document.getElementById( 'private' ).checked = '';


if (data.error) {
alert(data.error);
    }
                            }
                        } );
            }

        } );
```

and Yes my `message` column in SQL has collation `utf8_general_ci`.

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to encode the parameters you're passing:

```
       data     : "message=" + 
                  encodeURIComponent(message) + 
                  "&private=" + 
                  encodeURIComponent(privateidVal) + 
                  "&action=addcomment",
```

Alternatively, you can set up the "data" component as an object, and jQuery will do that work for you:

```
        data    : {
          message: message,
          private: privateidVal,
          action: "addcomment"
        },
```

Also while I'm at it, this line:

```
            if (privateid.is( ':checked' ) ? 1 : 0)
```

can be written more simply as

```
            if (privateid.is( ':checked' ))
```

The `.is()` function will return a value that's already directly usable in an `if` test.